# BLOB, how does it work

Tags: c, blob

I'm new to programming, and I have a premade code where a part of the computation is based on extraction some information from BLOB-files
I think I've found the place in the code, where the information is being read, but I don't understand it:

```
unsigned short decode_le16(byte *buf) {
    return buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8);
}


unsigned int decode_le32(byte *buf) {
    return buf[0] | (buf[1] << 8) | (buf[2] << 16) | (buf[3] << 24);
}
```

The BLOB's contain characters and numbers, but how is this information read? And how can I see the structure of the BLOB without prior knowledge of the layout?

Comment: The code you've shown is just for reading and converting binary data of opposite endianness - it's nothing to do with BLOBs *per se*. Note that a [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) is a general term for a block of binary data, and without further information I don't think anyone can give you any more detail.

Comment: Okay, but I'm pretty sure these two functions are being used to read from the BLOB. The BLOB is a binary file, am I right? But if I have no prior knowledge of how it's compressed, how can I get an overview of it? Like it's supose to contain a paper Id, a number of paper cites, references etc. but how can I get an overview of it, so I can start altering the code?

Comment: @1233023 indeed you need some info what is stored in the BLOB actually, to be able to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

> decode_le16

"le" stands for [little endian](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). 16 is size in bits. This code takes two (8 bit) bytes and combines them into a 16 bit integer using shift and bitwise OR operations, a fairly standard method of decoding endianness-independent binary formats.

> how is this information read

Some code not shown in the question must be using file I/O to retrieve a byte array from a file. This array is then fed piece by piece to functions like `decode_le16`. Then some other code assembles these integers, characters and whatnot into higher-level data structures.

> And how can I see the structure of the BLOB without prior knowledge of the layout?

You cannot, BLOBs are not structured by definition, they are just arrays of bits/bytes. If you must know and you don't have the format documented somewhere, you have to reverse-engineer it by tracing application code described above.